# How to calculate effect size Kappa Squared for multiple parallel mediators?

Tags: r, effect-size, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, path-model

I was using the function `mediation()` from the package [MBESS](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MBESS) to calculate κ<sup>2</sup> (kappa squared) as the effect size for a single mediator model. How can I calculate κ<sup>2</sup> for a multiple mediator model?

I'm aware of [Process](http://www.processmacro.org/) for SPSS and SAS, but would have to go through the process of installing either software and familiarizing myself with it, so I would prefer a solution for R. The Process FAQ states: "There are some ambitious folks translating some of the PROCESS models into R and Mplus code.  You can find those online." Unfortunately I haven't yet been able to find any of that R code, or none that fits my model (with two parallel mediators), so I hope one of you can possibly help me.

Here's my model:

[image: Structural Equation Model]

I didn't yet dare install [MEDMOD](https://r-courseware.wistia.com/projects/kdldkiyyph), as I'm on a Mac.

---

*Edit.*

Ha. I actually installed SPSS and Hayes' Process macro, only to find out that "κ<sup>2</sup> [is] available only in models with a single mediator" (Hayes, 2013, p. 432). Bummer. Have to read Preacher & Kelley (2011) again to see wether κ<sup>2</sup> only applies to single mediator models, and probably choose another effect size index.

Sources:

- Hayes, A. F. (2013). *Introduction to Mediation, Moderation, and Conditional Process Analysis*. New York: Guilford.
- Preacher, K. J., & Kelley, K. (2011). Effect size measures for mediarion models. *Psychological Methods*, *16*, 93-115.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regret to say that kappa-squared has some pretty big flaws, and its continued use probably does more harm than good. I no longer recommend it. Please see:

Wen, Z., & Fan, X. (2015). Monotonicity of effect sizes: Questioning kappa-squared as mediation effect size measure. Psychological Methods, 20, 193-203.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to come here and reply to my question. I very much appreciate your help.